# Docky hides when I maximize a window

Tags: docky, autohide, maximized

Docky hides every time I maximize a window. This is happening since I've upgraded to 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Klick on the docky-icon.

Under "Dock Configuration", change hiding to "none".

Then click close.